# Creating a static folder in node express that hosts index.html and other tsv files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, csv, express

I've been having trouble creating a static folder for a project using d3 node package. I've been using express to host a server.js which looks like this.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require('path');


app.use(express.static("public"));

var server = app.listen(8081, function() {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

This is purely to host an index.html file and a .tsv file which is called in the html file. My server directory looks like this

```
-Parent file
   -public
      |index.html
      |data.tsv
   -node_modules
    server.js
```

I get an error saying  Cannot GET /
I originally used a workaround of using a

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){res.sendFile(index.html);})
```

and this worked for just the html file, but now I need to use the .tsv file and this doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: the method in d3 that loads the data is

```
d3.tsv(<file>, function(error, d){ /* stuff you want executed after data loads goes here */});
```

Comment: Can you share how the tsv file is called in index.html?

Comment: I just made the edit

Comment: can you paste the console.log of error or d?

Answer (score 0):

`express.static("public")` will use the directory `public` relative to your working directory.

Make sure you start the script in the same directory as `server.js`. This is working for me as expected.

You can use

```
express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "public"))
```

and it will find `public` even when you are not starting from the same directory.

Comment: I have been running "node server.js" (which starts the script) while working in the Parent Directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on getting the `app.use(express.static('public'))`, after node server.js, in browser, attempt to GET `http://127.0.0.1:8081/data.tsv` . see if your browser can GET the file. If your browser can GET the file, there might be a typo in <file>

A work around might be:

```
app.get('/*',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('./public/'+req.url)
})
```

access index.html via `http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.html`, and when your browser, or d3js attempts to GET the tsv file via `http://127.0.0.1:8081/data.tsv`, node will serve `./public/data.tsv`